# What limitations exist when using a mounted AWS S3 drive versus a mounted EBS Drive?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to use AWS S3 storage for files that will be accessable from the web AND indexed by a search engine running locally on my amazon-linux EC2.  I want to use S3 rather than a more 'traditional' EBS drive because of the unlimited storage capacity that scales as I add more files -- meaning I don't need to mount additional EBS drives as this data scales past 1TB ( the max EBS drive size ).

I'm mounting the drive using [S3FS](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/).

What limitations will this system have over mounting multiple EBS drives and storing the files there? Will there be a considerable delay in access times, specifically when indexing millions of files from the mounted S3 drive with my search engine? Will I run into other problems accessing and manipulating these files with scripts on this machine?

I'm wondering because it seems like S3 is intended more for long term storage/backup and serving files to websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBS is 'traditional' because it is high performance and low-latency, suitable for databases for example. If you're just storing a bunch of files then S3 will be good and scalable. Indexing might be slower because of the slight latency increase, but if your indexer can parallelise its indexing then it shouldn't matter much. You would probably want to use an EBS volume to store the indexes themselves, or keep the indexes in RAM, otherwise the latency will hurt your application a fair bit... But it depends on your use case. Do some experiments.